# Direction of Uniform Electrical Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrons, electric-fields

An electron is travelling in a straight line through a vacuum with a constant speed of $1.5 × 10^7\text{ ms}^{–1}$.
The electron enters a uniform electric field at point A.
The electron continues to move in the same direction until it is brought to rest by the electric field
at point B. Distance AB is 2.0 cm.

What is the direction of the electrical Field?
[image: Image of the Question]

I thought that the direction of the electrical field would be from B to A such that it opposes the motion of the electron till it comes to rest but the answer states that the direction is from A to B. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

By convention, the direction of an electric field is the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field. What does that tell you about the direction of the force that a negative charge would experience if placed in the field?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the fact that the electron has a *negative* charge, so the field and the force are in opposite directions.